# How to click on an element, move the mouse over other elements and then select those elements that you hovered over with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, events, mouseevent, event-listener, jquery-ui-selectable

I am basically trying to replicate the `.selectable()` method of `jQuery` but I need it in `vanilla JavaScript`. Which `event listener` method should I use? I've tried with `mousedown`, but how can I detect that another element has been visited?
Here is an example on how `jQuery` does it: `[http://jsfiddle.net/ZfevM/99/]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. Had to work with `mouseup` and `mousemove` as well. Here is what I came up with and it works as expected: `[https://repl.it/repls/EquatorialLumberingInfinity]`

Any thoughts or alternative solutions are welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of window.getSelection() and [selection].getRangeAt([index]);

```
document
  .getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
  .addEventListener('mouseup', 
     function(){ 
       const selection = window.getSelection(); 
       const range = selection.getRangeAt(0); 

       console.log( selection, range ) 
  })
```

Selection has .containsNode() function to compare against given set; 
Range has .startContainer and .endContainer along with .commonAncestorContainer to compare against given structure